# Can a suspended user gain or loose reputation during the period of suspension?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Suppose when a user was banned, he had 1000 reputation points. Suppose he was banned for a week.

Now, assume that, in that one week, his posts received up and down votes amounting to an overall gain of 100 in the points.

(I know that for the one week of suspension his reputation will be locked at 1.)

..............................

My question is:

When he resumes after one week, will he start at 1000 or 1100?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During suspension period, account will be locked temporarily at "1 reputation ". After completion of suspension period, reputation will be recalculated.

Quoting from official [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the
>   complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in
>   timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days. That means:
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.
>
> At the end of this timed suspension period, **your reputation will be
>   recalculated, and your account will resume as normal.** We don’t hold
>   grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the
>   behavior improves, you are welcome back.

If suspended user receives upvotes to any of his posts, his rep will be added to previous rep. Whatever votes are cast, they are associated with posts.  After end of suspension period, reputation is recalculated based on upvotes and downvotes of all posts of user. If the user has any invalidated votes, he won't get any rep for those votes as they are invalidated or no longer exist.

In your example, suspended user resumes at 1100.

Comment: BTw the block quote does not explicitly say that a suspended user can gain/loose reps. On the other hand, it explicitly says that he can not post comments, answers etc.. IMO that blog post should be made more specific for the point i raised.

Comment: @Rickross Yes. That blog post doesn't explicitly say that.  But it says rep is recalculated and it would have been better if it had mentioned that.